# How to set region for script? Sikuli

Tags: python, automation, sikuli

My problem is that I do not know how to have my code run in a specific region -- it keeps scanning the entire screen instead. Here is my shoddy code if anyone could look at it.

```
running = True

def runHotkey(event):
global running
running = True

Env.addHotkey(Key.F1, KeyModifier.CTRL, runHotkey)
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0 
Region(Region(23,54,731,778))
while exists("1485901173411.png") and running: 

  click("1485900597943.png")    
  if exists(Pattern("1485900218788.png").similar(0.95)):
      type(Key.CTRL + "L")
      wait(1)
      type(Key.ALT + Key.ENTER)
      wait(10)
  else:
      click("1485901173411.png")
      wait(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, in order to limit the search area, you have to look for patterns inside a predefined region. There are few ways to define a region.

**Using coordinates**

For example, if you only want to look in the top half of your screen you can do:

```
topHalfScreen = Region(x, y, w, h)
```

and then:

```
targetPattern = topHalfScreen.find("targetPattern.png")
```

here you can also use `getScreen().getBounds().width` and `getScreen().getBounds().height` to determine screen size.

**Using pattern**

Pretty much the same idea but instead of defining screen area you look for a pattern that includes the one you want to find and then search inside it.

**Using relative pattern**

This way you can search for a pattern based on the location of another pattern. For example:

```
initialPattern = find("pattern.png")
actualRegion = Region(initialPattern.x + x1, initialPattern.y + y1, initialPattern.w + w1, initialPattern.h + h1)
```